# How to declare usages of root access android?

Tags: android, root

Some apps like Es File Explorer declare the usages of the root access, like this:

[image: Root usages are declared]

But "Unknown use of root privilege" is shown.
How do I declare root usages on my app?
I use `RootTools` library.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a standard root app feature, KingRoot itself contains that information for popular root apps to try and provide the user with more information.